Parenthesis around arguments of logs and trig functions
It is commonly used
$\sin x$ instead of $\sin (x)$, $\ln x$ instead of $\ln(x)$ and so on. I honestly always use parenthesis - even when they are usually omitted - because I feel they empathise the argument and therefore the fact that there is a function before  it(despite trig and logarithms being well-known functions).
I wonder whether this could be considered a mistake and what are the advantages of omitting parenthesis in the obvious cases (so the reason this "bad notation" is so widespread). Despite it not causing confusion (even though sometimes it leads to ambiguity) I feel like it doesn't make the information more obvious, but the opposite.

This is a question about opinions, not mathematics.

Not really, I asked a question at the beginning of the 2nd paragraph... do you mean that there isn't an objective answer to that question?

Whether it could considered a mistake, is a matter of opinion. The advantages of omitting parentheses is a matter of opinion.

Well, despite it being "bad notation",  this is widely used so I guess there are some clear reasons to justify that.

This question is similar to: Are there rules for omitted bracket use?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The dictionary does not dictate what words are used and how they are used, it merely attempts to show in what ways they are currently being used.  In the same way, notation is a form of language and while we try to have structure there is always the option for new or different ways of using notation.  Take falling factorials for instance... you'll see it written $~_nP_r$, $n\frac{r}{~}$, $(n)_r$, and more... Which is used is preference, and in some ways shaped by trying to avoid confusion.

@MartinBrandenburg thanks for your answer! So I guess it is not considered a mistake to always use parenthesis?

@Lorenzo Of course it's not a mistake. Just saying: I also use more parenthesis than strictly necessary. By the way I don't think that your specific question ("what are the advantages of omitting parenthesis in the obvious cases") is opinion-based. But the rest is, and hence it has been closed.

@JMoravitz thank you for this answer... if the aim is to be clear why are parenthesis omitted? Functions need an argument which is inside of a pair of parenthesis, so why aren't they used if they are correct and would avoid a lot of unnecessary confusion and ambiguity?

Use enough parentheses so that it is not ambiguous.  Don't use so many that it becomes unreasonable.  Noone should be writing $3x^3+2x^2+1$ as $(3(x(x(x)))+2(x(x)))+1$.  There is of course a balance that should be met.  Personally I don't find the parentheses after $\sin$ or $\ln$ cumbersome in normal circumstances (and I find them necessary in many, for instance for $\ln(x+1)$ so it isn't confused with $(\ln x)+1$).  On the other hand, if you have many appearing... as a dumb example, like $\ln 1 + \ln 2 + \ln 3 + \ln 4 + \ln 5$, by omitting the parentheses it saves ten characters...

@JMoravitz I think you can add your answer(s) to the mentioned duplicate. This will make it more easy to find.

I agree with you for the first part... in the case of multiplication there is no ambiguity involved... however, as for functions, I can't understand why they aren't used. Of course in some cases the argument is obvious, but it is still the argument and so it should be between two parenthesis. Ngl, I also dont like the fact that some arguments have parenthesis while others don't, it breaks a beautiful symmetry, but I acknowledge this is highly subjective

@MartinBrandenburg yeah I felt like it could have lead to some interesting discussions, but whatever...

Yes, but please notice that MSE is not for discussions. It's a question-answer site. For discussions reddit and probably some discords are better.

Oh okay. Thanks a lot for your patience
